# Deploy the vendors without Composer

Tags: symfony, deployment, build, composer-php

I usually deploy my vendors with a simple `composer install` in production.

I would prefer not using composer in production, so I'd need to build the vendors from my machine and deploy them in production.

I could copy the `vendor` directory but I'll certainly have to install other files like `app/bootstrap.cache.php` or other `autoloader.php`

2 questions so:

- What are these files I could install/update ?
- Are there any known practices to deploy pre-built vendors anyway ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `autoloader.php` is covered in `vendor` already.
Also copying `app/bootstrap.cache.php` should be fine.

What exactly issue do you try so solve? What advantage you'd like to get by not using `composer install` in production?

Comment: As you discovered, composer does more than just build the vendor directory.  After running composer update locally, you will need to upload your entire project directory to your shared host.  Then cross your fingers and hope that no absolute file paths are lurking around.

Comment: @TomášVotruba I'd like to run the less commands as possible in my productions, also some don't have outgoing access to any external network. @Cerad speaking of absolute paths, wouldn't there be some in `bootstrap.cache.php` anyway ?

Comment: Nope.  bootstrap will be fine.  It's all classes.  Earlier versions of Symfony had some issues with absolute paths.  They have been long since resolved but some third party bundles may still have problems.  Try it and see.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the procedure is pretty straighforward (at least it works for me that way): To deploy your application, you'd create a new directory, export the code from a tag into it (i.e. you don't export all repository-managing data like a `.git` directory). You then run `composer install --no-dev`, which will do some work, and should also run anything that is mentioned in the scripts in the `composer.json` file.

The result in this previously empty directory goes to the production server in whatever way you like, be it SCP, SFTP, rsync... There is no real "magic" going on here, essentially it is copying of files.

You may want to make sure you can roll back quickly, so I'd recommend to deploy every version into a designated directory, and then link the current version with a symlink. As an example: You had deployed your old version in `/srv/www/htdocs/app-1.0` and symlinked the directory `/srv/www/htdocs/app` to point to this directory. The vhost uses the generic `app` directory to serve the app.

The deployment will create a new directory `/srv/www/htdocs/app-1.1`, and putting it live will simply delete the old symlink and create a new one to the new directory. This should put your new version live instantly. Rolling back would mean to delete the symlink and create the one pointing to the old version again.

YMMV, because things like caches will affect the outcome, but this is not in the scope of how and where to use Composer to deploy software.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you for this great anwser. That's what I'm looking for. I will try that. Now that you say it reminds me the way Capifony does the deployments (maybe I should also take inspiration here).